# Count sets that sum to even number for given array

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

Let's say we have given array $A=\{A_1,A_2,\dots,A_n\}$, each $A_i$ is positive integer, we want to count sets of the array $A$ that sum to even number.

**Example**

Let $A=\{1, 2, 3\}$, there are $4$ sets that sum to even number, those are: $(\varnothing)$, $(1, 3)$, $(2)$ and $(1, 2, 3)$.

**My thinking**

The numbers aren't really important, but their parity is important, so let's say we have $a$ odd numbers and $b$ even numbers. The even numbers will always sum to even numbers, so we want to count ways we can chose even numbers of the $a$ numbers. My thinking is that we should count $$\left(\binom{a}{2} + \binom{a}{4}+\binom{a}{6}+\cdots\right)\cdot2^b$$

Is my thinking correct, and is there simplier way to do it.

Comment: Use the commands `\left` and `\right` before delimiters so that they resize to span the height of all the material they encompass

Comment: Why this prejudice against the empty set?  Its elements sum to zero, which is an even number.  If I were a member of the empty set, I would file a lawsuit against such discriminatory behavior.  Lucky for you that the empty set has no members!

Comment: And what about $1+2+3=6 $?

Comment: It is same if we count or not empty set, @HenningMakholm I made mistake in my example, it is corrected now.

Comment: @someone123123: You're still missing $\varnothing$, whose sum is $0$. $0$ is an even number because $0=0\cdot 2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there is at least one odd number, exactly half of all the subsets will contain an even number of odd numbers. So you get $2^{a+b-1}$ sums of each parity if $a\ge1$, and $2^b$ otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Any subset of even numbers of $A$, sums to an even number. We can add even number of odd numbers to these subsets to preserve the parity of the sum. So, given the set $A$ contains $a$ odd and $b$ even numbers, the number of subsets that sums to an even number is:$$2^b \bigg[\binom{a}{0}+\binom{a}{2}+\binom{a}{4}+\cdots\bigg] $$ And you can show that the term $\Big[\binom{a}{0}+\binom{a}{2}+\binom{a}{4}+\cdots\Big]$ is equal to $2^{a-1}$ for $a\geq1$ . So, the total number of subsets simplifies, as shown by Henning Makholm in his answer, to $2^{a+b-1}$.